# Extending a TypeScript interface from JavaScript: TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a function or null

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've a TypeScript interface like this:

```
export interface Foo {
  bar: string
}
```

This will compile down to an empty `.js` file.
So when using the TypeScript interface in an ES6 Node module, I'll get this error:

`TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a function or null`

A workaround will be to create a class

```
export class BaseFoo {
  bar: string
}
```

Now I can use `BaseFoo` from ES6 without getting the aforementioned error.
So it is not possible to just have interfaces in TypeScript with ES6 interop or is there an more elegant way than having `Base*` classes (which are not really base classes in the end) here?

Update: I understand the different concepts behind interfaces and base classes but my questions is about a best practice how to create a library in TypeScript which uses interfaces and how to build it in a way plain ES6 (which does not have interfaces) can also consume this library.

Comment: What do you mean use the interface ? Typescript will not let you use the interface since interfaces are just types and types are erased. You use interfaces to validate the type of values in typescript, at runtime there is no use for them.

Comment: A class implements an interface, it cannot extend one.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I updated the question.

Comment: @AlexanderZeitler the js consumer just does not care about the interfaces, the code is still usable, where an interface must be passed in they can just pass in an object literal that satisfies the interface (unchecked of course) or a class they create. You can create classes as well for the interfaces but I don't think there is a reason to do so unless you have another requirement..

Comment: If I don't create a `class` in TS I get the aforementioned error. I want to ensure the property signature of the `interface` from TS to be available as well.
So my current understanding is I can use the `interface` in TS as is but for JS interop I need to create a `class` that can be `extend`ed in plain JS without resulting in the error above. To act more `interface` like I also might throw `NotImplementedError`s in the class I'm `extend`ing.

Comment: @AlexanderZeitler You don't use the interface in TS either when creating object instances. You may write in TS `let a: MyInterface = { foo: 0 }` this same code is written in JS as `let a = { foo: 0 }` no interface, no error, works just as well no class required.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir In TS im currently using `class x implements y` where `y` is my interface. I understand that TS is not helping me in plain JS but tools like WebStorm do provide error messages if it can resolve the types + typings. Hence I want to export proper types but these need to be valid (e.g. no empty definitions like compiling TS `interfaces` produces) from the plain JS point of view as well.

Answer (score 2):

I think you my be misunderstanding how to properly use an interface. Interfaces are not "Base" objects, they simple define what an object should look like.

In typescript, many times an interface is used as a type for an object, but in general can be used to define what a class should "look like" as well.

For instance:

```
interface Foo {
  bar: string;
  baz: number;
  bang(): void;
}
```

In this case, any object/class that `implements` `Foo` will need to have these three things.

IE:

```
class FooImplemented implements Foo {
  bar = 'Hello World';
  baz = 42;

  bang() {
    print(this.bar);
  }
}
```

If I do not define bar, baz and/or bang; typescript will throw an error at compile time that I'm not properly implementing the `Foo` interface in the `FooImplemented` class.

To summarize, an interface tells the compiler what something is supposed to look like. And an interface can extend another interface. However, a class cannot extend an interface, but it can implement one. (Or multiple)

[Check out the docs on interfaces on typescripts website.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html)

Comment: I understand the different concepts behind interfaces and base classes but my questions was about a best practice how to create a library in TypeScript which uses interfaces and how to build it in a way plain ES6 (which does not have interfaces) can also consume this library.

Comment: @AlexanderZeitler the error suggests you're using `extends` instead of `implements` ?

Comment: @Evert `implements` does not exist in plain JS that's why I'm using `extends` and that's the reason why I'm looking for a workaround/best practice to handle this whole issue.

Comment: @AlexanderZeitler ah I understand now. Then the non-typescript equivalent really is not implementing/extending it all. There would be no point because the whole thing would happen in 'runtime' and typescript doesn't enforce anything at all in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use this [@implements jsdoc annotation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#implements):

```
/** @implements {Print} */
class TextBook {
  print() {
    // TODO
  }
}
```